# what are the benefits of custom extending `EventObject` and `EventListener`

Tags: java, events

what are the benefits of custom extending `EventObject` and `EventListener`
for event delivery? I see no different if I use interfaces without extending `Eventlistener` and `EventObject`.

references:- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/677591/Defining-Custom-Source-Event-Listener-in-Java

Answer (score 2):

The primary benefits would include the inclusion of the basic contract.  `EventObject` has a `getSource` method which indicates the source of the event.  It might not seem like much, but most people like knowing where the event originated from so they can make decisions about what they should do and it saves you having to re-invent the wheel.

`EventListener` provides you the ability to utilities the `EventListenerList`, which is a `protected` field in `JComponent`, meaning you don't need to devise your own management code to manage ever event listener interface you might design and you don't even need to create your own `EventListenerList` if you're extending from a `JComponent` based component.

Comment: You are right, It is totally make sense to me if I am extending from a JComponent based component. However, based my references, it didn't apply the `getSource` method(Everything just done what he made), it just nothing related to EventObject and EventListener, this is what I doubt about. :(

Comment: Based on your reference the `SpeedEvent` uses `super(source);`, as the weather the original poster intended to use it or not is another question.  This would come down to implementation, but providing the source of the event - IMHO - is always a good idea, as you may be listening to multiple event producers, just saying

Comment: is it possible when `myCar.speedUp(50);` , it directly trigger the listener? (Without applying `processSpeedEvent(new SpeedEvent(this, this.maxSpeed, this.minSpeed, this.currentSpeed));`

Comment: Yes, but typically, what you do is provide a `fire` event method.  This means that if any body overrides you class and needs to raise a related event for some reason, they can.